Falsely connected lines when exporting elevation contours to DXF
I'm reaching out to get help with an exporting issue for contour lines from a dataframe.
My goal is to get a DXF file representing the elevation contours in the way shown here:
Desired output
However, I'm getting this:
Actual output (falsely connected lines)
That's the input format:



X (Easting)
Y (Northing)
Z (Elevation in m)




312581.9
6457327.5
84.88


...
...
...



Here's my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import ezdxf

# See input format in the table above. 

# Extract the x, y, z columns
x = cut_out_df['x'].values
y = cut_out_df['y'].values
z = cut_out_df['z'].values

# Create a grid to interpolate the data
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):200j, min(y):max(y):200j]  # Grid with 200x200 resolution
grid_z = griddata((x, y), z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')  # Interpolation

# Create the contour lines
contour_levels = np.linspace(np.min(grid_z), np.max(grid_z), 10)  # Define contour levels
contour_data = ax.contour(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, levels=contour_levels)

# Export contour data to DXF
doc = ezdxf.new()

# Create a new model space in the DXF document
msp = doc.modelspace()

# Iterate through the contour collections
for level, collection in zip(contour_levels, contour_data.collections):
    # Get the paths of the contour lines
    for path in collection.get_paths():
        vertices = path.vertices
        # Create a polyline for each contour line
        polyline = msp.add_lwpolyline(vertices, close=False)
        # Add a layer or set a specific attribute to identify the contour level
        polyline.dxf.layer = f'Contour_{level:.2f}'
        
# Save the DXF document
doc.saveas('contours.dxf')

I thought the close=False would solve the problem but then recognised that there can be multiple "islands" of the same elevation height. which are in fact separate entities.

LWPOLYLINE is the wrong DXF entity for this task. Use add_polyline3d() instead.

Thanks for the hint @mozman! That makes more sense.
But I'm getting the same result with the adaptation like:
vertices_3d = [(x, y, level) for x, y in vertices]
and then:
polyline = msp.add_polyline3d(vertices_3d)

Thanks again to mozman giving the initial hint.
I could solve the issue in the following way:

# Code as above followed by ...

doc = ezdxf.new()
msp = doc.modelspace()

for level, collection in zip(contour_levels, contour_data.collections):
    for path in collection.get_paths():
        for segment in path.to_polygons():
            if len(segment) > 1:
                vertices_3d = [(x, y, level) for x, y in segment]
                if np.allclose(vertices_3d[0], vertices_3d[-1]):
                    vertices_3d.pop()

                polyline = msp.add_polyline3d(vertices_3d)
                polyline.dxf.layer = f'Contour_{level:.2f}'

Checking with if np.allclose(vertices_3d[0], vertices_3d[-1]): and then using vertices_3d.pop() did the trick to remove the points that always been connected in the export.
